# Some Software Missing After BSOD

Tags: windows, windows-10, bsod, memory-management

A few days ago I was running Windows 10 on my custom built PC and it had been running reliably for a year, but suddenly I got a BSOD and the error was MEMORY_MANAGEMENT. I restarted it and found that what the error was. No problem there. But when I logged on, I saw some stuff missing from the toolbar, but only the image was missing and it wouldn't launch. The computer still connects to the internet, but Chrome or even Internet Explorer would not launch, I only got the loading circle and when it went away, nothing else. I tried tried troubleshooting but found nothing.

Specs:
Motherboard: MSI Gaming 970
Ram: 16GB DDR3, 2 cards at 2100MHz (I think) and 2 at 1600MHz
Graphics card: AMD R9 280
CPU: AMD FX-6300 6-Core

Comment: Sounds like corruption, reinstall Windows

Comment: Yes but I don't want my stuff to be deleted

Comment: Stuff has already been deleted...

Comment: Not all of it, BeamNG, Steam, Minecraft are still there with pretty much everything. Only thing that is my main problem is I can't launch Chrome or Edge

Comment: I suggest you perform a Reset, doing so, will solve this problem.  Your personal files, if you elect to keep them, won't be deleted.

Comment: How do you reset

Comment: Search for "Reset this PC" in the start menu.

Comment: It's really hard to launch the search for some reason and when I do, nothing comes up even when searching the control panel :(

Comment: Its there keep looking for it.

Answer (score -1):

Check all your drives are in place in computer.
I had an issue like this once, except my internal hard drive had become disconnected during operation. The .lnk can't find the specified program.